# Using wildcards for filenames in powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp, automation, wildcard

I am having a lot of issues trying to automate downloading from an ftp site.  I know the folder the file will be in, and I know that it will be a .zip file.  However I do not know what the files will be named.

So I have code that works if I know the file name...for example:

$sourceuri = "ftp://myFtpSite/test/myZipFile.zip"

I would like to be able to use wildcards in this string so it will recongize any zip file.  So I could write something like

$sourceuri = "ftp://myFtpSite/test/_.zip"

and it would download any zip file in that folder.

Comment: Did you try "ftp://myFtpSite/test/*.zip"?  From an FTP client perspective, I use mget and specifies wildcards like *.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient, but have you considered just using the console app ftp.exe?  You can build a text file with commands (such as "mget *.zip" to retrieve all .zip files) and automate the process.

```
ftp -s:filename
```

Comment: +1 because that'll work but it's not exactly doing it within powershell.